# How can I find the task name in task manager when I know the application name automatically using python?

Tags: python

Some cases Application name and task name in task manager differs. For example, App name is 'Groove Music' and task name in task manager will be 'Music.UI.exe'. 
How can I get the task name when I know the app name

Answer (score 0):

It should just be 'Python', 'Python (32 bit)' or 'Python (64 bit)'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine multiple Windows APIs:

1. Identify the window handles to get the window names.
2. Map the handles to Process Ids
3. Get the application name (*.exe) for each process id.

First and second step can be done using `EnumWindows`, `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `GetWindowText` using pywin32.

The last step could be done using command-line tool `tasklist` or query WMI.